# Batch Insert/Update with Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, performance, hibernate

According to the Hibernate doc, the best way to do a bulk insert is that :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Actually, I'm using Hibernate with Spring (`@Transactional`), so I don't use `Session` and methods `flush()` and `clear()`.

I have major problem with performance : 1 hour to insert 7400 rows...

I think Spring is mismanaging the session and disconnects from the database between calling a method of the DAO class.

How to check that ?

Comment: Do you use pooled datasource?

Comment: Then the connection should not be disconnected.

Comment: @Jens **I use** `<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">` **and not** `<orcl:pooling-datasource id="dataSource"
        url="${jdbc.url}" username="${jdbc.username}" password="${jdbc.password}"/>`